# Trouble with Medication Timings

Tags: hl7-fhir

Using the FHIR medication Schedule/Timing structure, what is the recommended way to represent these two frequencies: 1) For one hour every 21 days (e.g. for chemo infusions), and 2) Every 4-6 hours.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well, after discussion within the FHIR project team, it appears that you'll have to use extensions for the moment, and that this will be addressed in R2 of FHIR.

Answer (score 0):

This example may help:

http://hl7.org/fhir/2016Sep/medicationorder0317.json.html

excerpt
....

```
"dosageInstruction": [
{
  "text": "Rapid daily-dose escalation, until tolerated, from 3 mg/d, and then 10 mg/d, to the recommended maintenance dose of 30 mg IV over 120 min, 3 times per wk on alternate days for up to 12 wk",
  "additionalInstructions": [
    {
      "text": "Rapidly increase dose until tolerated"
    },
    {
      "text": "Administer on alternate days"
    }
  ],
  "timing": {
    "repeat": {
      "duration": 12,
      "durationUnit": "wk",
      "frequency": 3,
      "period": 1,
      "periodUnit": "wk"
    }
  },
  "route": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
        "code": "47625008",
        "display": "Intravenous route (qualifier value)"
      }
    ]
  },
  "method": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
        "code": "422145002",
        "display": "Inject - dosing instruction imperative (qualifier value)"
      }
    ]
  },
  "doseQuantity": {
    "value": 3,
    "unit": "mg",
    "system": "http://loinc.org",
    "code": "mg"
  }
},
{
  "text": "Rapid daily-dose escalation, until tolerated, from 3 mg/d, and then 10 mg/d, to the recommended maintenance dose of 30 mg IV over 120 min, 3 times per wk on alternate days for up to 12 wk",
  "additionalInstructions": [
    {
      "text": "Rapidly increase dose until tolerated"
    },
    {
      "text": "Administer on alternate days"
    }
  ],
  "timing": {
    "repeat": {
      "duration": 12,
      "durationUnit": "wk",
      "frequency": 3,
      "period": 1,
      "periodUnit": "wk"
    }
  },
  "route": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
        "code": "47625008",
        "display": "Intravenous route (qualifier value)"
      }
    ]
  },
  "method": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
        "code": "422145002",
        "display": "Inject - dosing instruction imperative (qualifier value)"
      }
    ]
  },
  "doseQuantity": {
    "value": 10,
    "unit": "mg",
    "system": "http://loinc.org",
    "code": "mg"
  }
},
{
  "text": "Rapid daily-dose escalation, until tolerated, from 3 mg/d, and then 10 mg/d, to the recommended maintenance dose of 30 mg IV over 120 min, 3 times per wk on alternate days for up to 12 wk",
  "additionalInstructions": [
    {
      "text": "Rapidly increase dose until tolerated"
    },
    {
      "text": "Administer on alternate days"
    }
  ],
  "timing": {
    "repeat": {
      "duration": 12,
      "durationUnit": "wk",
      "frequency": 3,
      "period": 1,
      "periodUnit": "wk"
    }
  },
  "route": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
        "code": "47625008",
        "display": "Intravenous route (qualifier value)"
      }
    ]
  },
  "method": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
        "code": "422145002",
        "display": "Inject - dosing instruction imperative (qualifier value)"
      }
    ]
  },
  "doseQuantity": {
    "value": 30,
    "unit": "mg",
    "system": "http://loinc.org",
    "code": "mg"
  }
}
```

]